# Java how to add application from the other class into gui class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've got my Keypad class separate and I want to run it from the other class (gui), so I can have whatever I want in my gui class (some btn etc.) and then in the bottom my Keypad.

When I try `Keypad kp = new Keypad();` I get almost what I want but they're displayed in separate windows I want them to be in the same window.

That's the Keypad class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeypadWork extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton buttonR = new JButton("Reset");
private JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
private JButton buttonE = new JButton("Enter");



public KeypadWork() {
    setTitle("Keypad");

    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 2, 2));
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        addButton(new JButton(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    addButton(buttonR);
    addButton(button0);
    addButton(buttonE);

    this.pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}

private void addButton(JButton button) {
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Please Share your code,

Comment: and when I add in my main class `Keypad kp = new Keypad();` both windows appear and I want to see my main window and Keypad to be inside the main class gui

Comment: If you don't want the `KeyPadWork` instance to be in a separate window, then you shouldn't make it a `JFrame`. If you want it inside another window, extend `JPanel` instead and add the `KeyPadWork` instance to some other `JFrame` using the normal AWT `Container.add(Component)` method.

Comment: ok I got it now, thanks

Comment: @Alderath Please turn your comment into an answer that

Comment: @knowbody Please accept Alderath's comment if turned into an answer

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution, thank you @Alderath

> If you don't want the `KeyPadWork` instance to be in a separate window, then you shouldn't make it a `JFrame`. If you want it inside another window, extend `JPanel` instead and add the `KeyPadWork` instance to some other `JFrame` using the normal AWT `Container.add(Component)` method.

Thanks a lot!